# Why is this GLSL shader producing a syntax error?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm fairly new to using/writing shaders so I may be missing something, but the following GLSL fragment shader is producing a syntax error.

**retro-frag.glsl**

```
#version 440

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform ivec3 precision; // A syntax error happens on this line for some reason

void main() {
    vec3 prec_fac = vec3(float(1 << precision.x), float(1 << precision.y), float(1 << precision.z));
    vec3 factor_adjust = 1.0f / (prec_fac - 1.0f);
    vec4 color = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
    vec4 low_color = vec4(
        floor(color.x * (prec_fac.x + 0.01f)) * factor_adjust.x,
        floor(color.y * (prec_fac.y + 0.01f)) * factor_adjust.y,
        floor(color.z * (prec_fac.z + 0.01f)) * factor_adjust.z,
        1.0f);

    gl_FragColor = low_color;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <cmath>

constexpr sf::Uint8 ColorFloatToU8(float val) {
    return static_cast<sf::Uint8>(255.0f * val);
}

sf::Color ColorFromHSV(float hue, float sat, float val, float alpha=1.0f) {
    int i;
    float f, p, q, t;
    sf::Uint8 a = ColorFloatToU8(alpha);
    sf::Uint8 r,g,b;

    if(sat == 0) {
        r = g = b = ColorFloatToU8(val);
        return sf::Color(r, g, b, a);
    }

    hue *= 6.0;
    hue = std::fmod(hue, 6.0f);
    i = std::floor(hue);

    f = hue - i;
    p = val * (1 - sat);
    q = val * (1 - sat * f);
    t = val * (1 - sat * (1 - f));

    switch(i) {
    case 0:
        r = ColorFloatToU8(val);
        g = ColorFloatToU8(t);
        b = ColorFloatToU8(p);
        break;
    case 1:
        r = ColorFloatToU8(q);
        g = ColorFloatToU8(val);
        b = ColorFloatToU8(p);
        break;
    case 2:
        r = ColorFloatToU8(p);
        g = ColorFloatToU8(val);
        b = ColorFloatToU8(t);
        break;
    case 3:
        r = ColorFloatToU8(p);
        g = ColorFloatToU8(q);
        b = ColorFloatToU8(val);
        break;
    case 4:
        r = ColorFloatToU8(t);
        g = ColorFloatToU8(p);
        b = ColorFloatToU8(val);
        break;
    default:
        r = ColorFloatToU8(val);
        g = ColorFloatToU8(p);
        b = ColorFloatToU8(q);
    }

    return sf::Color(r, g, b, a);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Creating RenderWindow\n";
    sf::RenderWindow window(
        sf::VideoMode(800, 600),
        "SFML window",
        sf::Style::Close,
        sf::ContextSettings(0, 0, 0, 4, 4, sf::ContextSettings::Default, true)
    );

    std::cout << "Loading Shader\n";
    sf::Shader shader;

    // vvv ATTENTION: This is where the glsl shader is failing to compile! vvv
    if(!shader.loadFromFile("retro-frag.glsl", sf::Shader::Fragment)) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Unable to load shader!\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Creating Image : ";
    sf::Image img;
    if(!img.loadFromFile("sample_photo_00.jpg")) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Unable to load image!\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Creating Texture\n"; std::cout.flush();
    sf::Texture tex;
    tex.loadFromImage(img);
    sf::Texture tex2;
    tex2.loadFromImage(img);

    std::cout << "Creating Sprites\n"; std::cout.flush();
    sf::Sprite sprite(tex);
    sf::Sprite sprite2(tex2);
    sprite2.setPosition(400, 0);
    shader.setUniform("texture", sf::Shader::CurrentTexture);
    shader.setUniform("precision", sf::Glsl::Vec3(3, 3, 2));

    std::cout << "Starting Game Loop\n"; std::cout.flush();
    while(window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::Green);
        window.draw(sprite);
        window.draw(sprite2, &shader);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Github Gist link: https://gist.github.com/drako0812/0f47ad46f6d4b4c5c15b234cbc15e280

Edit: the specific error output is the following:

```
Failed to compile fragment shader:
Fragment shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: 0:4: error(#132) Syntax error: ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated
```

Edit 2: added the c++ code that loads the shader.

Edit 3: Solved. The corrected GLSL shader is below:

**retro-frag.glsl**

```
#version 440 compatibility

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform ivec3 bit_precision; // A syntax error happens on this line for some reason

void main() {
    vec3 prec_fac = vec3(float(1 << bit_precision.x), float(1 << bit_precision.y), float(1 << bit_precision.z));
    vec3 factor_adjust = 1.0f / (prec_fac - 1.0f);
    vec4 color = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
    vec4 low_color = vec4(
        floor(color.x * (prec_fac.x + 0.01f)) * factor_adjust.x,
        floor(color.y * (prec_fac.y + 0.01f)) * factor_adjust.y,
        floor(color.z * (prec_fac.z + 0.01f)) * factor_adjust.z,
        1.0f);

    gl_FragColor = low_color;
}
```

Also, in main.cpp the line `shader.setUniform("precision", sf::Glsl::Vec3(3, 3, 2));` should now be `shader.setUniform("bit_precision", sf::Glsl::Vec3(3, 3, 2));`

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @NicolBolas sorry about that. The error message is now added.

Comment: Is that the actual InfoLog you get back from OpenGL, or is that something else? Also, I suspect your loading code is at fault; let's get a full [mcve].

Comment: That is the output when debugging with Eclipse CDT on Windows 10 using  mingw64 from msys2, but I will try and show a more complete example for  this.  By the way, the shader is loaded using SFML 2.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line will give an error:

```
uniform ivec3 precision;
```

because `precision` is a keyword, and you can't use a keyword as a variable name. It is used for precision qualifiers. While precision qualifiers have no functionality in desktop OpenGL shaders, they were added to the syntax for compatibility with shaders from OpenGL ES.

Also note that the `texture2D()` function you use here is deprecated in the core profile:

```
vec4 color = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
```

In the core profile, this is replaced with the overloaded `texture()` function:

```
vec4 color = texture(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
```

Actually, if you use `gl_TexCoord`, you will need to use the compatibility profile anyway. This is not available in the core profile. So unless you completely transition to the core profile, the first line in your code needs to be:

```
#version 440 compatibility
```

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Yeah it is supposed to be a compatibility profile. Like I said, I'm fairly new to GLSL.  It is difficult to learn techniques when examples one can find on the internet aren't exactly clear what version of OpenGL they are for and whether it's for compatibility or core profiles.